# Cron jobs in PHP for Socket programming

Tags: php, cron, gps

I am developing one website to track the GPS device(s). I am configuring the devices (GPS) to the host name and specific port number to establish the connection to my hosted server and send the coordinates in regular interval like 1 minute-5 minutes.

I wrote a PHP page to start the socket server to accept the requests from socket clients (GPS devices) and parse them before storing in the database. Up to this working fine.

My problems are:

1. I need to keep on open the listener page, If I do this from cron jobs they have limitation like cron job can run for few minutes only.
2. In case the Server listener page stops/aborted, the port is not closing automatically as it is aborted. To use the same port we need to restart the system which is not possible when hosting.

Please help what is the correct approach.

My Major issue now is how to close the opened socket port when the page is aborted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

leaving sockets open will not be supported by many hosters. The only way to keep a socket alive, is to run your own server. Because a hosting server is hosting many websites, a continious running cron job asks too much resources from the server. (What if everyone runs cronjobs all the time, the server would crash in no-time...)

My advise, look at a VPS or start hosting your own server and you can run it as a system task :D

To be more clear to your question, just PHP won't get you where you want to go ;-)

Comment: I'm with @CyberK on this one. I also just recently programmed, a socket server, for the exact same thing. I can't imagine it being possible on an shared host. I wrote mine to be a daemon, starting the daemon at startup or from shell. So get your own dedicated *nix server up and running instead of a shared host. You could look at VPS.net or MediaTemple (dv)

Comment: you seems to be correct. I need to use my own server (static IP) for this purpose.

Comment: @AjayR Have you faced any issue in dedicated server currently we are facing issue like at some interval of time(around 10 hours) we are unable to get data to server than we need to kill port process and rerun process and then it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem are you using a infinite loop to listen to the socket connection? Else please do that.

Maybe for the second problem you could use PHP's register_shutdown_function function. Not really sure. Try this:

Create a function that would try and close the connection and register it as a shutdown function.

Comment: Yes I am using inifinite loop, how to close the opened socket incase someone stops loading the page.